# Install pip for python 3.5

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip, tensorflow

**SOLUTION** My user did not own permissions to the pip directory, I reinstalled Python 3.5 using the `sudo -H` flag

I'm trying to install Tensorflow for python 3.5 using pip3 -- for reasons described in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3196#issuecomment-231114859) github issue -- but when I install using `sudo pip3 install *.whl` it installs to python 3.4.

How can I redirect `pip3` to install into my python 3.5 directory?

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04

```
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ python3.4 -m pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ python3.5 -m pip --version
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip
```

It looks like I don't even have pip installed for python 3.5. How can I do this?

I've tried

```
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ pip install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.4.egg
```

Also,

```
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/X11/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3.4 /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

I can't find any support for upgrading to pip3.5

**UPDATE**

```
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-headers-4.2.0-27 linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.2.0-27-generic python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ sudo python3.5 easy_install.py pip
python3.5: can't open file 'easy_install.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ python3.5 -m ensurepip
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install pip3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip3


kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-headers-4.2.0-27 linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.2.0-27-generic python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ python3.5 -m ensurepip
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

As recommended by @fwalsh

```
kendall@kendall-Macmini:~/Downloads$ python3.5 get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

It seems like I'm missing all sorts of dependencies -- I'm going to try reinstalling

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py

Comment: `pip already up to date`

Comment: @fwalch I added update, it seems I'm missing all sorts of dependencies -- going to try reinstalling 3.5

Comment: so were you able to install pip for python3.5? How did you do that part? That is what the question title is about but it seems you already did that?

Comment: Can you take the solution, answer your own question, then accept the answer? This would be the approved way to reply to your own question!

Answer (score 17):

Check: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

You'll either have Pip there or easy_install(part of Pythons setup tools), which can be used to install Pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo python3.5 easy_install.py pip
```

Or you can try:

```
python3.5 -m ensurepip
```

Another option is attempting to install from a repository, the package name depends on your distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip pip3
```

**Edit:** Try this correction for easy install:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/easy_install.py pip
```

I'm assuming that's the directory it's installed to.

Also, you're missing this library for the `python3.5 -m ensurepip` command:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: added update in the post. I'm beginning to think my python 3.5 install went wrong somewhere. Should I reinstall?

Comment: updated again, and again, is something wrong with my python 3.5 install? lol

Comment: Did you install it from a repository or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: I installed from the source https://www.python.org/downloads/ although now that I think about it, I'm beginning to think I installed the wrong source (wrong OS?) I clicked on the large `Download Python 3.5.21 button at the top of the page -- I'm running linux **SCRATCH THIS IDEA**

Comment: `easy_install.py` simply does not exist in my python 3.5 directory

Comment: I've added a few extra commands to try and help. Looks like Python setuptools is missing if you don't have easy_install. And the Open SSL library is ensurepip is complaining about a lack of SSL

Comment: adding the setuptools still doesn't add easy_install. same error message -- what's with the `3 not upgraded` ?

Comment: Try installing the open ssl library and running ensurepip again. It's a surefire way for Python to retrieve a copy of Pip when you need it.

Comment: it's as if it is only seeing python 3.4. trying to reinstall python 3.5 now. This could also be a problem with the latest 3.5 release, I'm also going to try reinstalling with older releases

Comment: Ah I found the issue! My user did not own the pip directory, I had to use the -H flag

Comment: weird my `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` is completely empty. Not even pip. But I `python3.5` command seems to work fine.

Comment: You can copy the pip package to it from another 3.x installation. Then do: python3.5 -m pip install --upgrade pip to make sure it's the most recent version. The -m makes it look in dist-packages for pip - unless you've installed a python3-pip deb package or created a bash alias you won't be able to just use 'pip3'

Comment: The correct install is `apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: What if I am not on Linux so I don't have `apt-get`?

Comment: My `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` is completely empty...

Answer (score 1):

All the various Python 3.* versions seem to re-use the same pip location, which makes it difficult to call for a specific Python version.

However, you can call pip for a specific version by specifying it as a module. So instead of doing:

```
pip3.5 install <blah>
```

which doesn't exist on most distros, do:

```
python3.5 -m pip install <blah>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-venv

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2

python3 -V
```

Comment: The question is looking for python 3.5 version