# Tensorflow won't import in my Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I followed the tutorial on Tensorflow's web site, when I type `Pip3 list` I can see Tensorflow 1.4 in the list but when I start the Python terminal I can't import it, it says that there is `No module named 'tensorflow'`

even when I type `Pip3 show tensorflow` I can notice that it exists

Comment: Do you open the terminal with `Python3`?

Comment: yes, I did, but I could not import tensorflow  !!

Comment: in the terminal what do you get typing `import sys; sys.version_info`

Comment: @Chris_Rands this is the output : `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: Can you locate the installation folder of the package? Is it contained in the output of `sys.path`?

Comment: @AmosEgel what would you me I do for  you exactly??

Comment: I would suggest to do two things: 1. check the output of `import sys; sys.path` to see the python path (that is where python looks for modules) 2. see if the tensorflow package was indeed installed into one of these folders.

Comment: `pip3 show tensorflow` shows where it's currently installed, part 2 of [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152279/tensorflow-wont-import-in-my-python#comment83283901_48152279)

Comment: @Steve Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Comment: import sys; sys.path
['', '/root/anaconda/lib/python36.zip', '/root/anaconda/lib/python3.6', '/root/anaconda/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/root/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

Comment: @Steve should move tensorflow directory or add its path to this one

Comment: It seems that your `pip3` refers to Python 3.5 whereas your `python3` refers to Python 3.6. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820625/how-to-use-pip3-for-python-3-6-instead-of-python-3-5) for a discussion how this can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have two versions of Python 3 installed simultaneously. `pip3` installed the package to Python 3.5, but `python3` opens a Python 3.6 session, where tensorflow is not among the installed packages.

In other words, the reason for your problem is a mismatch between the `pip3` version and `python3` version.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820625/how-to-use-pip3-for-python-3-6-instead-of-python-3-5) adresses how to change this conflict. You can either modify the `$PATH` variable such that `python3` also points to Python 3.5, or uninstall one of the two python versions.