# PIP3 associated with the wrong python version

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am aware that this kind of question has been asked many times. I even found out this almost identical issue: [How to use pip3 for python 3.6 instead of python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820625/how-to-use-pip3-for-python-3-6-instead-of-python-3-5?rq=1)
But I still yet get my problem solved. I am using os x.

I have three versions of pythons: 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.10

python3 --version
Python 3.7.4
```

but if I do

```
pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

I do not know why pip3 is pointed to 3.6 not 3.7 (while python3 gives me 3.7)

if I do

```
python3 
import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

I have

```
['/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

PIP3 pointed to python 3.6 instead of 3.7. How do I make it point to python 3.7?

I try add python3 to the path but to no avail. I do not want to uninstall python 3.6.

Comment: What happens if you run `pip3.7 --version`?

Comment: pip3.7 --version
-bash: pip3.7: command not found

Comment: If you have installed Python 3.7 via Homebrew (`brew install python/python3`), then `pip3.7` should be installed. Check `brew doctor` for errors.

Answer (score 7):

Make a habit of using the following;

```
python -m pip install <package> # and you will be sure to have the package attached with the right version of python
```

Eg:-

```
$ python3 -m pip install requests
```

Comment: thanks for this. but what if I still want pip3 --version associated with pyhthon 3.7 not 3.6?

Comment: There's no point in wanting that. But anything is possible. You could symlink it after installing the the latest `python3-pip`, if your distribution provide one. But using the `-m` option with `pip` module is exactly the why it exists. It make sure your packages are tied with the correct python :)

Comment: Follow han's advice, avoid the `pip` or `pip3` or whatever scripts as much as possible. Prefer using _pip_'s executable module instead: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip`. For some more background info: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 2):

```
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3 

$ nano /usr/bin/pip3
```

At first line of the file, you should see

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Just change it to the python version you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
or
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
```

Save it. Done!

Comment: This worked for me, with the difference being that the new shebang that worked for me was `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` as I had recently switched from Canonical's `python3` to the one built from the current source downloaded from python.org.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using this in the bash_profile

```
alias pip3='/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip'
```