# Python, cant use mechanize - No module named 'mechanize'

Tags: python, mechanize

hope u can help me.

i have the problem that i cant use mechanize in Python. i really dont know why.

My python version is: Python 3.10.9

i just wrote this in a python file:

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
```

and the Error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\stackoverflow.py", line 1, in 
> import mechanize
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mechanize'

thanks guys!

before you ask, yes i installed the last version of mechanize on my windows computer like this:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>pip3 install mechanize
Requirement already satisfied: mechanize in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib>=0.999999999 in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from mechanize) (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from html5lib>=0.999999999->mechanize) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from html5lib>=0.999999999->mechanize) (1.16.0)
```

Comment: Does `pip3 --version` point to the same python as `where python3`?

Comment: C:\Users\Daniel>pip3 --version
pip 22.3.1 from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: no, just my windows 10 computer

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no. The first one is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip" and the second one is: "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe"

Comment: There you go! Your `pip3` is installing packages to a different python installation than what runs when you do `python3`. This is why the better way of installing packages using pip is to do `python3 -m pip install ...`, which ensures that the same `python3` you use when you run a command is used to call `pip install ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIP3 associated with the wrong python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645600/pip3-associated-with-the-wrong-python-version) (I know it's a Mac question and you're on Windows, but the solution is the same)