# python3.5 on raspberry pi

Tags: python

Hello i am new to Raspberry pi,
I set up Rasbian on my Raspberry pi3, python3.7 is set up by default on the software, so pip3 is directly calling python3.7 and setting up the libraries on python3.7.

I installed python3.5 on the OS, but I can not use pip3 for python3.5, since when I am using pip3 -V command it shows ( pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python3.7))

My python3.5 has no pip file in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages

The question now how to make pip3 linked to python3.5 instead of python3.7.

Comment: Why do you want to use 3.5 over 3.7?

Comment: @JammyDodger the same reason people want to use 2.7 over current version :)

`Pure insanity`.

Comment: I tried to work with tensorflow on 3.7 but it seems not to be working good on python3.7 and gives errors while setting up packages.

Answer (score 1):

Type python3.5 in terminal and check if you are able see python 3.5 shell, if you do then install all packages using command

`python3.5 -m pip install "package-name"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i use that it returns /usr/local/bin/python3.5 : No module named pip

Comment: You need to install pip for python 3.5 you can refer link below  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249961/install-pip-for-python-3-5